# How to call a function within a class from another script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, object

Class Script:

```
class Test2:

def __init__(self):
    self.a=10
        
    self.sq()
    
def sq(self):
    print(self.a*2)
    
def call_later(self):
    print("Called Later")
```

Calling Function from another script:

```
from test2 import *
import time

Test2()

time.sleep(30)

#I want to call this function without creating the object again
Test2.call_later()
```

How do I call a class function later on after the object has been created?

Comment: *"without creating the object again"* The save the created object?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call an instance method on a class. So either you instantiate the class (like shown in the above answer) or you make the method static and the member variable a class variable:

```
class Test2:
    a = 10

    @staticmethod
    def sq():
        print(Test2.a * 2)
```

and then you call the static method:

```
Test2.sq()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an object of the class so

```
from test2 import Test2

Test2().sq()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put both file in the same directory then create an instance of your class Test2 like this:

```
from test2 import Test2()
test2 = Test2()
test2.sq()
```

I hope it helped you